# Cygwin и Vim и проблема с компиляцией плагина YouCompleteMe

Tags: плагин, vim, cygwin

Здравствуйте. Я пытаюсь скомпилировать плагин YouCompleteMe для Vim, но вылезает ошибка. Вот что получается:

```
tampi@Ilya-PC ~/.vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe
$ ./install.py --clang-completer
Searching Python 2.7 libraries...
ERROR: unable to find an appropriate Python library.
```

Python2.7 установлен.

Comment: там явно намекаеют, что нет питона версии 2.7

Comment: @KoVadim Питон 2.7 видишь? -нет -а он есть

Comment: в любом случае, можно и подгуглить http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37277976/vim-youcomplete-me-unable-to-find-an-appropriate-python-library

Comment: @KoVadim T_T голова кругом идет от такого английского, можешь объяснить, что изложено там, только на русском и понятно?